# How do I change the colour of the first LI value that is added through a XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am working on a project where the user can go to a particular page and browse a particular feed. This feed is dynamically added through an `XMLHttpRequest`, which will give a `#Cat=(value)` parameter to the PHP parser, which will then carry out the appropriate action.

Within this page, there are several LI elements that will be used for the user to filter/cycle through the feeds.These LI elements will be different for each page - they are dynamically added from the database.

I have successfully managed to change the colour of the LI whenever the user clicks on that particular LI or if the URL changes to include the category.

I have done this by: downloading all categories from the database, and displaying them appropriately. I then get the #Cat= value from the URL, and perform a switch statement - if the Cat value equals the LI value, then change the LI value's colour.

My problem, however, is that the first LI (regardless of the page, it isn't a typo) will not change. For example: one page will have the url `#Cat=Front` Page, if I click on the category Front Page it will not change because it is the first LI. On another page, the url will also be `#Cat=Front` Page and if I click on the category Front Page it will change the colour because it is not the first LI.

I presume it is my `JavaScript/JQuery` that is causing the issue.

**`JavaScript/JQuery:`**

```
activeCat("Default");

$(window).on( "hashchange", function()
{
    var Url = window.location.href;
    var Category = Url.substring(Url.indexOf("#Cat=") + 5);
    var Cat = decodeURI(Category);
    activeCat(Cat);
});

function activeCat(cat)
{
    switch (cat)
    {
        case "Default":
            $("#channelCategories li").first().css("color", "#2980b9");
            break;
        case "Front Page":
            $('ul li').each(function(i)
            {
                if($(this).hasClass('channelCategory'))
                {
                    $(this).css("color","black");
                }
            });
            alert("Channel has front-page category");
            $("#channelCategories li:contains('Front Page')").css("color", "#2980b9");
            break;
        case "United Kingdom":
            $('ul li').each(function(i)
            {
                if($(this).hasClass('channelCategory'))
                {
                    $(this).css("color","black");
                }
            });
            $("#channelCategories li:contains('United Kingdom')").css("color", "#2980b9");
            break;
```

**`PHP:`**

```
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData))
{
    $Category = $record["Category"];
    if($i <= 5)
    {
        $html .=    "<a href='#Cat=$Category' class='noLink' id='$Category'><li class='channelCategory noLink Text'>$Category</li></a>";
    }
    else if ($i > 5)
    {
        //$dropContent[$j] .= "<a href='#Cat=$Category'><li class='channelCategory itemLink Text'>$Category</li></a>";
        $dropContent[$j] .= $Category;
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

My Question: when the category is default, how do I change the colour of the first LI? Also when viewing the first LI, how do I change the colour of it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who tried to help me. I do not understand why my code was not working, but I have implemented a work around: when the first li is added, I am adding a unique class name to its anchor tag - and to select the first li I am merely searching for that class name.

Comment: Take a look at this, it's easy to target most things with css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type e.g. `ul li:first-of-type { /* style properties */ }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With your solution, would the li not permanently be shown in a different colour?

Comment: Provide some context on the rules governing when the colour should change and why it changes please

Comment: Just a note: you should only use the `id=` attribute once per page. You're looping through and giving an `id` multiple times on the category for example. If the categories are unique then perhaps its fine. (I don't know that though)

Comment: The colour should change when the user clicks on the LI, but by default (aka when the page first loads) the first LI will automatically be coloured. My issue is the first LI doesn't change colour by default, nor when I click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace `id` to `class` in tag `<a>` (jQuery selector with `id` get always the first item) then try add/remove class (`$( ).addClass('firstDefault')` and change color using css.

Debuggin it, var `Cat` really come with "Default" value?

Comment: My issue is that only the first LI cannot be changed etc. Is it due to me using id over class, or would it be because of something else?

Comment: I don't think I did exactly what you suggested, but your answer pointed me in the right direction I think. I still do not understand why my code was not working, but I have implemented a work around. When the first li is added, the li's anchor has a unique class name and I am merely searching for that class name as a way to select the first li. Very messy.